# Current Google Login Authorized redirect URIs how to fill exactly correct

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, oauth2client

I try to login google at https://www.MYDOAMIN.com/register/signUp but I get error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () and [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

So which mean is Authorized redirect URIs fill wrong? Or is server issues???
Here my Authorized redirect URIs
[image]